# How to open a modal from an Angular component in page full of multiples components

Tags: angular, typescript, components

```css
@import '../../theme/conf';
.edit-input {
    padding: 0 2%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 7px 0;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid $fonts-color;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.todolist-wrap {
    padding-bottom: 13px;
}

.form-group {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.new-task-input {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    flex: 1;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $border-color;
    outline: none;
    @include transition(all 1s);
    &:focus {
        border-bottom: 1px solid $primary;
    }
}

.task-list {
    border-radius: 5px;
    @include transition(all 0.4s);
    &:hover {
        background: rgba($primary, .8);
        .edit-input,
        .enter-task-edit,
        .cancel-task-edit {
            border: 1px solid $white;
        }
    }
}

.list-text,
.list-over {
    display: inline-block;
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 39px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis
}

.list-over {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.cyclo-btn {
    position: relative;
    top: 19px;
    right: 10px;
}

.over-btn {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 15px;
    @include center(40px, 39px);
    .fa-square-o {
        margin-left: -2px;
    }
}

.enter-task-edit,
.cancel-task-edit {
    width: 30px;
    margin: 7px 0;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid $fonts-color;
    border-left: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    outline: none;
    &:hover {
        background: rgba($white, .1);
    }
}
```

I have tried to launch my modal from an angular component in page with multiple components but unfortunately my application stop working and the application get freezed.[image]

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TodoListService } from './todolist.service';
import {Task} from '../../models/task.model';
import swal from "sweetalert2";
@Component({
  selector: 'du-todolist',
  templateUrl: './todolist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todolist.component.scss'],
  providers: [TodoListService]
})

export class TodolistComponent implements OnInit {

  todolist: Array<any> = [];
  newTaskText: string;


  constructor(private todoListService: TodoListService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.todoListService.getTasksByUserId(221).subscribe(
      (item: Task[]) => {
        this.todolist = item;
    });
    this.todolist.forEach(item => {
      item.isOver = false;
      item.isEdit = false;
      item.editText = item.title;
    });
  }

  edit(index) {
    if (!this.todolist[index].isOver) {
      this.todolist[index].editText = this.todolist[index].text;
      this.todolist[index].isEdit = true;
    }
  }

  overMatter(index) {
    if (!this.todolist[index].isEdit) {
      this.todolist[index].isOver = !this.todolist[index].isOver;
    }
  }

  enterTaskEdit(index) {
    this.todolist[index].text = this.todolist[index].editText;
    this.todolist[index].isEdit = false;
  }

  cancelTaskEdit(index) {
    this.todolist[index].isEdit = false;
  }

  creatNewTask() {
    const newTask = new List;
    newTask.isEdit = false;
    newTask.isOver = false;
    newTask.text = this.newTaskText;
    this.todolist.unshift(newTask);
  }

  openModal(modal) {
    modal.open();
  }

  closeModal(modal) {
    modal.close();
  }

  onClose() {
    swal({
      type: 'success',
      title: 'Success!',
      text: 'close it!',
    });
  }

}
export class List {
  text: string;
  editText: string;
  isOver: boolean;
  isEdit: boolean;
}
```

```html
<div class="todolist-wrap">
  <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:7px">
    <input type="text" class="new-task-input" [(ngModel)]="newTaskText" (keyup.enter)="creatNewTask()">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="creatNewTask()">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group task-list" *ngFor="let item of todolist;let i = index">
    <button class="over-btn" (click)="overMatter(i)" *ngIf="!item.isEdit">
      <i class="fa fa-square-o" *ngIf="!item.isOver"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" *ngIf="item.isOver"></i>
    </button>
    <label class="list-text" [ngClass]="{'list-over':item.isOver,'list-text':!item.isOver}" (dblclick)="edit(i)" *ngIf="!item.isEdit"
      title="{{item.title}}">{{item.title}}</label>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(myModal)">open my modal</button>
    <input type="text" class="edit-input" [(ngModel)]="item.editText" *ngIf="item.isEdit" (keyup.enter)="enterTaskEdit(i)">
    <button class="enter-task-edit" *ngIf="item.isEdit" (click)="enterTaskEdit(i)">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="cancel-task-edit" *ngIf="item.isEdit" (click)="cancelTaskEdit(i)">
      <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
    </button>

    <modal #myModal>
      <modal-header>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
      </modal-header>
      <modal-content>
        <p>Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse.
          Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth.
          Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip
          quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.</p>
      </modal-content>
      <modal-footer>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="closeModal(myModal)">close</button>
      </modal-footer>
    </modal>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a simple code of my toDoList Components , i tried to open the modal in Dashboard where i have included my toDoList Components and others components but when i click the button the application freeze and every thing stop working.

Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: position the model outside of the todolist-wrap div.

Comment: can you share your css code, it looks like an z-index problem. try to increase the z-index of your model

Comment: I add the css file

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example modal calling in angular bootstrap. I have created stackblitz for you. You can use this logic to your app.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-modal-muthu

Html

```
<button id="openModalButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Open Modal</button>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
           <h5> Welcome to Muthukumar Demo Page</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
             <h1> Hello World! Muthukumar is trying to became Full Stack Developer..</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hello Karnan my goal is to open a modal in a multi components page and the call to open this modal is in one components in the page i tried your code and the application freeze !

Comment: Hello Your respense helped me it was the balise card that prevent the modal from opening

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for all,

It was the call of my components

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <card cardTitle="Todo List" isCollapse="true">
      <du-todolist></du-todolist>
    </card>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <card>
      <profile></profile>
    </card>
  </div>
```

i changed outside the balise card and the modal works now!

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <du-todolist></du-todolist>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <card>
      <profile></profile>
    </card>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <card>
      <weather></weather>
    </card>
  </div>
```